# Swift: How to perform Segue for different UITableViewCell to different ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have a `HomePageTableViewController`, which contains three customized `TableViewCell`, each `TableViewCell` contains a `UICollectionView`. I want to perform segue when user tapped on each `TableViewCell` and go to different `ViewController` to show the detail of the `CollectionView`. I used this code:

```
import UIKit
class HomePageTableViewController: UITableViewController, PostDelegate {

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell1") as! HomePageTableViewCell1

        cell.getCategory()
//            cell.scrollToNextCell()
//            cell.startTimer()
            cell.postDelegate = self
            tableView.rowHeight = 260
            return cell
    }

     else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell2") as! HomePageTableViewCell2

        cell.getCategory()
        tableView.rowHeight = 140


        return cell
    }
     else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell3") as! HomePageTableViewCell3

        cell.getCategory()
        tableView.rowHeight = 470
        return cell
    }

}


func selectedPost(post: Posts) {
        //You will get your post object here, do what you want now

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: post)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


    let post = sender as! Posts

    let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailTableViewController
    postDetailPage!.passPost = post


}
```

this code does the job whatever which `TableViewCell` I tapped, it goes to the same segue with identifier "goToDetail". for example, for the `HomeTableTableViewCell2`, I want to perform segue with identifier "goToDetail2" and so on. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking your code looks like you have created one protocol and created the instance inside all 3 `CustomTableView` cell. After that you are calling that delegate method on selection of your collectionView.

To solved your problem just create one more parameter of type `Int` with your protocol method and pass the `CustomTableView` index with it.

So now your protocol `PostDelegate` will be looks like this.

```
protocol PostDelegate {
    func selectedPost(post: Posts, index: Int) 
    //Others method if you have
}
```

Now call these method from your different cell like this way

In `HomePageTableViewCell1`

```
self.postDelegate.selectedPost(post: post, index: 0)
```

In `HomePageTableViewCell2`

```
self.postDelegate.selectedPost(post: post, index: 1)
```

In `HomePageTableViewCell3`

```
self.postDelegate.selectedPost(post: post, index: 2)
```

Now change the implementation of `selectedPost` method inside `HomePageTableViewController` like this

```
func selectedPost(post: Posts, index: Int) {

    if (index == 0) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: post)
    }
    else if (index == 1) {
        //Perform segue with Second ViewController
    }
    else {
        //Perform segue with Third ViewController
    } 
}
```

**Edit:** To know which segue you have perform inside `prepareForSegue` you can use `segue.identifier` for that.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "goToDetail") { 
        let post = sender as! Posts
        let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailTableViewController
        postDetailPage!.passPost = post
    }
    else if (segue.identifier == "secondViewSegue") { 
        let post = sender as! Posts
        let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController
        postDetailPage!.passPost = post
    }
    else { 
        let post = sender as! Posts
        let postDetailPage = segue.destinationViewController as? ThirdViewController
        postDetailPage!.passPost = post
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks first. I have a question, how about `prepareForSegue`, how should I choose which `ViewController` as the `destinationViewController`? thanks

Comment: For that simply you need to use `segue.identifier`, check my edited answer.

Comment: right now since I haven't implement anything inside the secondViewController, but it successfully works as I want, I will try to add some code inside the secondViewController to see if it works. thanks

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy coding :)

Comment: I am implement this solution to another case, when I tapped on the cell, didSelectedItemAtIndexPath works, but it won't perform the segue, do you know where I may forget to add? @NDoc

Comment: yeah, its working on one project, I don't know why the other one is not working, I guess I gorget some part maybe. still can't find now

Comment: Can you give me your project link?

Comment: I found the error, I forgot to set the delegate for `TableViewCell2` and `TableViewCell3`. Now it's working perfectly fine. thanks so much

Comment: I know you will make it:)

Comment: Hello @NDoc I have Some Issue Please Help Me Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @NDoc Here It is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093356/how-to-make-dyanamic-nsdictonary-in-swift

Answer (score 2):

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let myWebView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(" Your ViewController") as! Your ViewController
            self.presentViewController(myWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let myWebView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(" Your ViewController") as! Your ViewController
            self.presentViewController(myWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
         if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let myWebView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Your ViewController") as! Your ViewController
            self.presentViewController(myWebView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
     }

Hope It Help. Thanks.
```

Comment: this will lead me to the different view controller, however, in my cause I did `self.prepareSegueWithIdentifier` inside the `func selectedPost`, so that I can get the data from the cell and pass it to the detail view controller, can this solution do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override method `didSelectCell:atIndexPath`. There you should check which cell was pressed(first second etc...). After that you need to have three segues in you controller (each segue should be from one controller to other controller, not from table view to controller). When you determine your next controller you can call method `perfromSegueWithIdentifier` that will show needed controller.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectCell cell: UITableViewCell onIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let identifier: String? = [0 : "Identifier1", 1 : "identifier2", 2 : "identifier3"][indexpath.row] {
        self.perforSegueWithIdentifier[identifier]
    }
}
```

This code was writen fast without checking it's semantic correctness, so it may have some issues inside. But it should help you to understand what I'm talking about. As well I used `Dictionary` intead of `switch` or `if else` because as for me it look better, you can use anything you want to define which cell was pressed. Hope it helps...

Comment: right now, the `goToDetail` segue is connect between the `HomePageTableViewController` to the `DetailTableViewController`. what do you mean "each segue should be from one controller to other controller, not from table view to controller"? do you mean I need to drag the segue from different cell to the view controller, not from the table view controller to the view controller? thanks

Comment: As I understand you need to show three different controller differs to pressed cell.

Comment: You need to have three segues for each controller, you can' have one segue for three controllers.

Comment: yes, I have three different segue with different identifier, but how can I decide which one to use. cause in the `HomePageTableviewController` I have a `func selectedPost(post: Posts) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: post)

}` to get data from the `CollectionView` inside each `TableViewCell`. so I guess I need to chose the segue identifier inside this function.

Comment: thanks, I will have a look and try to understand, cause I am new to swift, thanks.

Comment: No problems, fill free to ask me if it's hard for you

Answer (score 0):

If you use the delegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` you will receive an indexPath. Once you have this, use it to get the cell you have tapped on by calling `self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`. After that you can get the reuse identifier (cell.reuseIdentifer) and then perform an if/else to perform the correct segue.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if (cell.reuseIdentifer == "TableViewCell1")
    { //Do segue one
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail", sender: post)
    }
    else if(cell.reuseIdentifer == "TableViewCell2")
    { //Do segue 2
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToDetail2", sender: post)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain a little more in detail, sorry I am new to Swift. thanks

Comment: For your solution currently, @Avinash Mishra's answer will work, however if you start to combine cells with different reuse identifiers within one section then my answer would be the better solution.

Comment: right now I use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier` in the `func selectedPost`, so I can't use it inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @LeoGuo Actually, if you are wanting to use the prepareForSegue method, use my solution as using presentViewController will display the viewController immediately and you won't be able to set any of your variables.

Comment: @LeoGuo is there a specific reason why you are using that function? If not you could just move that code into didSelectRowAtIndexPath because that will be called automatically when you tap on a row.

Comment: cause before I use `didSelectedRowAtIndexPath`, it can perform the segue,  but no data passed from the cell to the detail ViewController, I use this function `selectedPost` to pass the data, its from the delegate `postDelegate` which I add on the top of my `HomePageTableViewController`. thanks

Comment: @LeoGuo Okay, it seems like a slightly confusing way of doing things. If you're wanting to distinguish betweens cells then this is probably the easiest way of doing so but you should maybe rethink how the data is going to be passed.