# how to make Dyanamic NSDictonary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, nsdictionary

```
{
   “QuizId” : “23566656”
   “StartTime”:”23:30”
   “EndTime”:”23:45”
   “data”:[
      {“QuestionID”:”131313131”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313141”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313151”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313161”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313171”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313181”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313191”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
      {“QuestionID”:”131313101”,“AnswerID”:“1233152”},
   ]
}
```

Hello I want to Create a `NSDictonary` on Runtime which Structure Should Be Like above. any Help Will Appreciated Thanks.

**I Got Solution Thanks For That Effort**

Little Change I want to Make 
As i Have Modal For all Those Data.

```
    let info = self.playQuizArray[currentQuizIndex] as! playInfo
    let Ainfo = info.answers[indexPath.row] as! AnswerInfo
    let QuesID = info.quizQId
    for i in 0..<playQuizArray.count {
        data.append(["QuestionID": QuesID[i], "AnswerID": playQuizArray[i]]) // For Answer Ainfo.ansID  
    }
    let dic = [
        "QuizId" : "23566656",// info.quizID
        "StartTime" : "23:30",
        "EndTime" : "23:45",
        "data" : data
    ]
    print(dic)
```

Thanks.

Here Is The Modal

```
class AnswerInfo: NSObject {

    var ansId  :String? = ""
    var ans    :String? = ""
    var ansImg :String? = ""

    class func infoWith(dict: NSDictionary?) -> AnswerInfo {
        let anInfo = AnswerInfo()
        anInfo.wrapInfo(dict)
        return anInfo
    }


    func wrapInfo(dict: NSDictionary?)  {
        if dict == nil {
            return
        }
        self.ansId     = dict!.objectForKey("answerId")  as? String
        self.ans  = dict!.objectForKey("AnsImage")  as? String
        self.ansImg = dict!.objectForKey("option")    as? String
    }
}

class playInfo: NSObject {

    var quizId :           String? = ""
    var quizQId :          String? = ""
    var quizQuestion :     String? = ""
    var answers = NSArray()



class func  PlayQuizInfo(dict: NSDictionary?) -> playInfo {

let Pinfo = playInfo()
    Pinfo.WrapPlayQuiz(dict)
return Pinfo
}
    func WrapPlayQuiz(dict: NSDictionary?)  {
        if dict == nil {
        return
        }
        self.quizId           = dict!.objectForKey("quizId")    as? String
        self.quizQuestion     = dict!.objectForKey("question")  as? String
        self.quizQId          = dict!.objectForKey("questionId")as? String

        if let answer = dict?.objectForKey("keys") as? NSArray {

        let AnsArray = NSMutableArray()
            for ans in answer {
            let ansInfo = AnswerInfo.infoWith(ans as? NSDictionary)
                AnsArray.addObject(ansInfo)
            }
            self.answers = AnsArray
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is objective C but you tagged in Swift,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik in SWIFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use swift `Dictionary` `[String: AnyObject]` this way instead of `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
var data = [[String: AnuObject]]()
for i in 0..<questionArr.count {
    data.append(["QuestionID": questionArr[i], "AnswerID": answerArr[i]])
}        
let dic = [
    "QuizId" : "23566656",
    "StartTime" : "23:30",
    "EndTime" : "23:45",
    "data" : data
]
print(dic)
```

Comment: Plaese Help as I did Edit Thanks For Help . @NDoc

Comment: @AvinashMishra is QuesID is array?, also please so the model class `playInfo` and `answerinfo` that give more detail

Comment: Edit Done as per Your Need Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashMishra one  playInfo have multiple answer, how are your differentiate the selected answer?

Comment: Those are the Option For Ans to Display and will have to select One Ans to Send Back To Server  Every QUestID will Have One AnsID in Array .

Comment: That was i am asking are you storing some where selected answer array? or you want to just create dic of `playInfo` object.

Comment: Not Storing just Creating Dic

Comment: How should i know which answer user selected?

Comment: I have to show one Question out of many so i did Indexing and Incresing on  Did Select Row on (Table View ) so data.append(["QuestionID": info.quizQID, "AnswerID": Ainfo.ans]) will work but  it gives me an error.

Comment: Type 'String?' has no subscript members

Comment: Also use force binding with ans and quizQID with `!`

Comment: wher i can share my project?

Comment: Have you try force wrapping using `!` as i told you?

Comment: worked Force wrapping Thanks. but now the issue is if my array is having 10 count then same QuedID and AnsID is repeating as no of count is

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying, you need to add a new question with your new code that you have try that will helpful to understand where you reach, Don't forgot to add the code of your data array append operation on didSelection of answer..

Comment: Sorry For late As it Worked Like A charm and Your Effort was priceless  Thanks a Ton.

Comment: How are you?  How to convert and sent the dictionary to server in Swift. Thanks

Comment: Hello @NDoc  How Are you . I am Facing a New Issue Please Have a look . Help Me  Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241987/inside-datataskwithrequest-is-not-executing-in-swift-while-hitting-the-api

Comment: where inside DataTask @NDoc

Comment: @AvinashMishra Don't understand what issue you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

Add dynamic values to the corresponding keys and it will work.

```
let dynamicDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        dynamicDictionary.setValue("23566656", forKey: "QuizId")
        dynamicDictionary.setValue("23:30", forKey: "StartTime")
        dynamicDictionary.setValue("23:45", forKey: "EndTime")

        let arrayOfDictionaries = NSMutableArray()
        for _ in 0..<4{
            let questionAndAnswer = NSMutableDictionary()
            questionAndAnswer.setValue("131313151", forKey: "QuestionID")
            questionAndAnswer.setValue("1233152", forKey: "AnswerID")
            arrayOfDictionaries.addObject(questionAndAnswer)

        }

        dynamicDictionary.setValue(arrayOfDictionaries, forKey: "data")
        print(dynamicDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
//Contruct the dic like this
var dic: [String: AnyObject] = ["QuizId": "23566656",
                               "StartTime": "23:30",
                               "EndTime": "23:45",
                               "data":[[String: String]](count: 7, repeatedValue: ["QuestionID":"131313131","AnswerID":"1233152"])
                                ]

// And now retrive value like this

let quizId = dic["QuizId"] as! String
let StartTime = dic["StartTime"] as! String
let EndTime = dic["EndTime"] as! String
let data = dic["data"] as! [[String: String]]
```

Comment: Plaese Help as I did Edit Thanks For Help.