# Inside dataTaskWithRequest is not Executing. In Swift While Hitting the API

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Same Data when I am hitting with POSTMAN I m getting the desired response. But in my Function  inside **dataTaskWithRequest**  I am Not Getting Any Response.

```
func sendData (){
            let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/quiz-school/mobileData/request.php?request=QuizTotal&module=PQ")!
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = try!  NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
                if(error != nil){
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                ((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
            }
            task.resume()
}
```

On DATA TASK

[image: My Code Break Point]
After Data Task

[image: After DataTaskWithRequest]
POSTMAN RESPONSE
[image]
Thanks Any Help Will Be appreciated.

My Dictionary Which I am Sending

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            answer =             (
                9353091
            );
            question = 31675931;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353101
            );
            question = 31675936;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353111
            );
            question = 31675941;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353121
            );
            question = 31675946;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353131
            );
            question = 31675951;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353141
            );
            question = 31675954;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353151
            );
            question = 31675961;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353279
            );
            question = 31676023;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353289
            );
            question = 31676026;
        },
                {
            answer =             (
                9353299
            );
            question = 31676031;
        }
    );
    end = 5565665;
    quizId = 1206500;
    start = 5565656;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting error?

Comment: No error @PayalManiyar

Comment: Have you print the response?

Comment: @PayalManiyar Inside  dataTaskWithRequest Nothing is  Executing not even a single Line From dataTaskWithRequest execution goes to task.resume()

Comment: What do you mean by not getting a response: is the callback not executed, are you receiving a nil response, another thing?

Comment: What makes you think that there is no response? Is this a compiled iOS project or in the Playground?

Comment: @NDoc I Have Edited The Question Please Have A look

Comment: As stated above, `dataTaskWithRequest` fetches the data **asynchronously.** The callback will be executed **later,** when the data has arrived, not when you schedule the request.

Comment: @MartinR I  am  a Newbie in Swift as i am Compiling Each Line in this My Compiler Did Not Navigate inside DataTaskWithRequest as i Also updated My Question Please Have A look. Thanks

Comment: It will execute in back ground told you that, add print statement after initialization of dictionary, `print(dic)`

Comment: @NDoc Where Should i print (Dic ) inside Func or where I am Making Dict

Comment: @NDoc Nothing is Happening after print(Dic)

Comment: Can you share Dictionary you are passing?

Comment: try `print(response)` and show us to output.

Comment: @Mr.UB Nothing is happening in (response) and i also ADD the Dictionary.

Comment: other APIs are working fine?

Comment: ya Working Perfect @Mr.UB

Comment: Do one thing: _Open Postman, click body->click Bulk edit -> Copy the content_ and paste here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122260/discussion-between-mr-ub-and-avinash-mishra).

Comment: Nothing happens because *your code does nothing*. Simple as that. The task is empty - no printing, nothing; just a dic declaration.

Comment: @EricAya Then What To Do Now Can You Show Me the Way Please.

Comment: @EricAya No Change  nothing happning

Comment: @Mr.UB Here is The Content Of Bulk EDIT request:QuizTotal
module:PQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting code working on my side based on our discussion:

```
//MARK: URLRequest

func sendData (){

    var dict = [String:AnyObject]()

    dict =
    [
        "data" : [
                [
                    "answer" : [9353091],
                    "question" : 31675931
                ],
                [
                    "answer" : [9353101],
                    "question"  : 31675936
                ]
        ],
        "end" : 5565665,
        "quizId" : 1206500,
        "start" : 5565656
    ]

    print(dict)

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/mobileData/request.php?request=QuizTotal&module=PQ")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = try!  NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let task =  NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ data, response, error in
        if(error != nil){
            print("ERRORRRRRRR : \(error)")
            return
        }

        print("RESPONSEEEEE : \(response)")

        do {
            let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject]

            print("DIIIIIIIC \(dic)")
        }catch {
            print("adsfdasfdsfdsafdsfadsfs")
        }

        ((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**Final Edit:**

The OP did not had issue in the above mentioned code. After hours of discussion and chat with him I saw that the error was in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, the project was crashing immediately after the `sendData:` method was called, hence not response was received from the server.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: ya Thats Right . This Was Happening to my App thanks .@Mr.UB

Comment: hello @Mr.UB I have Found Another One.

Comment: Can WE Discuss about It in room

Comment: If the issue is tricky, you should post a new question, other Users can also help of it.

Comment: Not Yet am still trying

Comment: almost Solved But There Is Isuue Please Have A look http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334182/swift-how-to-pass-array-data-from-uiviewcontroller-to-uitableviewcell-class